# No Accounts tab in Xcode preferences

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to import a developer profile which was previously exported. According to [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW16):

> To import your developer account assets
>   1. Choose Xcode > Preferences.
>   2. Click Accounts at the top of the window.

However, I don't see Accounts tab in Preferences:

[image]

How to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those instructions are for Xcode 5. If you want to see your profiles on Xcode 4 you need to go to the Organiser. It's in the Window menu.