# Install Apple Developer Certificate in Xcode.

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

I am very new to ios development.

I was trying to build an app with phonegap. 
It is working fine on simulator.

But to create an ipa file, i need to install Apple developer certificate in xcode.

For that i am unable to see the **account tab** in **key binding** panel of xcode.

My Xcode version is 4.6.2.

Can anyone please tell me where to install apple developer certificate in xcode.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915805/no-accounts-tab-in-xcode-preferences

Comment: Update XCode to actual XCode 6 before we go on to figure out any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 4 is no longer supported.
**Update to Xcode 6** and it will take care of all your certificates/provisioning issues (as long as you have an up-to-date Apple Developer membership)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for it

- Download Profile and Double click on it. Automatically it will add in Xcode and Keychain.
- Another way is Xcode -> Preferences -> Account -> Add Accounts if you have not added -> Click on Download Manual Profiles